# Errors after changing the type of a variable to an Observable (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, debugging, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

After changing the type of a variable to an Observable, I get error messages elsewhere in my code that I can not handle.

The Observable within a **authService** I have created like this:

```
private activeBusinessCase = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
public activeBusinessCase$ = this.activeBusinessCase.asObservable();
```

In the same service, I receive the error message..

> Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject '

..for this line of code:

```
this.router.navigate ([Constants.routing.explorer + this.activeBusinessCase.toLowerCase ()]);
```

---

Within my **home.component.ts** I get the following error message..

> Property 'activeBusinessCase' is private and only accessible within class 'UserAuthService'.

..for this lines of code:

```
ngOnInit () {
  this.router.navigate ([Constants.routing.explorer + this.authService.activeBusinessCase.toLowerCase ()]);
}
```

---

But the most important error message is in my **httpService**, in which nothing works anymore:

```
  getResource (key: string, lang: string): Observable <any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders ({'Accept': 'text / html'});
    return this.httpClient.get ('/ resources /' + key,
      {
        headers: headers,
        responseType: 'text',
        params: new HttpParams ()
          .set ('businessCase', this.authService.activeBusinessCase? this.authService.activeBusinessCase:
            environment.default_business_case)
          .set ('long', long)
      }) Pipe. (
      catchError (() => {
        return this.translateService.get ('Not-available'). pipe (
          map (res => '<h4 style = "text-align: center">' + res + '</ h4>'));
      })
    );
  }

  getResources (long: string): Observable <Resource []> {
    return this.httpClient.get <any> ('/ resources',
      {
        params: new HttpParams ()
          .set ('long', long)
          .set ('businessCase', this.authService.activeBusinessCase? this.authService.activeBusinessCase:
            environment.default_business_case)
      });
  }
```

Here the error message in the console sais:

> error TS2341: Property 'activeBusinessCase' is private and only accessible within class 'UserAuthService'.

---

I am still a beginner in Angular and thankful for any detailed help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can try to help but you dont have a question, anyway...

1.you cant use toLowerCase on anything else than a string ( the observable/subject can emit a string but its not a string)
[observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables)

2. if you set a property private you cant use it anywhere else. use the public one.

what do you exactly want to archieve?

Comment: I have set the type of activeBusinessCase to Observable to use subscribe on it and get the current value (BehaviorSubject). Everything works, except for the mentioned error messages.

My goal is to get the value of activeBusinessCases everywhere, which is set in the authService as an Observable. So the lines posted in my question should work again like before.

Comment: okay, then you have to subscribe to it and use the returned value for the first one and to solve to the other two you can use activeBusinessCase$

Comment: So instead of: this.authService.activeBusinessCase ? this.authService.activeBusinessCase :
            environment.default_business_case --> this.authService.activeBusinessCase$ ? this.authService.activeBusinessCase$ :
            environment.default_business_case? Is that enough? No need to subscribe here also?

Comment: sorry you are right, you have to subscribe to it all the cases and use the returned value

Comment: Ok, I'll try it and get back to you :)